# HTTP POST in javascript in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, http, post, firefox-addon

I'm a newbie trying to do a simple HTTP post in JS within a Firefox extension..

This isn't passing through the parameters:

```
var params = "a=1&b=2&c=3"
req.open('POST', 'http://www.mywebsite.com/');
req.send(params);
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've included the header to tell the server what type of request body you're sending it:

```
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

(Assuming `req` is an `XMLHttpRequest` created earlier in the code.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an extension, plain JavaScript can do this:

[Asynchronous cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467008/asynchronous-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Comment: He is specifically looking to do this _within_ a Firefox extension. Whether or not an extension is necessary is irrelevant.