# Javascript sending data via POST in firefox addon

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a mysql database, with a php form.  Normally, people use the php form on my website to add to the mysql database.  I have been building a firefox addon to let them use the form without visiting the site directly to add data to the mysql database.  Now I am stuck...

I have the form data I want to add to the mysql database, but how can I send it to the mysql database from the addon?  What's the best way to do this?  Would you send it to the php form first or is there a direct way?  Is it possible to go straight to mysql?  The firefox addon is coded in javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about FF's extensions. But I'm pretty sure you can make a XHR (AJAX) request somehow. Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan Hančič is right : the best way is to use XMLHttpRequest.

Here's an example :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("post", "http://ex.ample.com/file.php", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4) {
        // Do something with this.responseText
    }
}
xhr.send("var1=val1&var2=val2");
```

There are plenty of tutorials and references on the web about AJAX and the xhr object.

Comment: "There are plenty of tutorials and references on the web about AJAX and the xhr object." This being the official Mozilla one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Ajax would be the way to go. This post may be helpful to you: [HTTP POST in javascript in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176359/http-post-in-javascript-in-firefox-extension).

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to send data but do not use xmlHttpRequest directly in your code.

Use a popular javascript library like jquery to send data to the server.

**Edit**: Removed irrelevant parts about browser compatibility.

Comment: But he is building an addon for firefox, so compatibility shouldn't be an issue

Comment: You still might want to use jQuery for other reasons, of course, but yes, compatibility is not one of them in this case.