# HTTP Post with JS (Firefox Extension)

Tags: javascript, rest, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a FireFox Extension...
I would look to make a http post to a desired url.


I am looking to do something similar to this post.
[HTTP POST in javascript in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176359/http-post-in-javascript-in-firefox-extension) 
I have also read through Mozilla including... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript "Using FormData bound to a form element"

The URL(Lambda Function) I am sending this to is not receiving the request. I have not been heavily exposed to javascript. Also, I don't know if there is something I am missing since this is being built as a Firefox Extension.

I have implemented this is my code.

```
    document.addEventListener("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
      var params = "test=test"
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
      req.open('POST', 'https://sdlurjb3zi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/contMang');
      req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      req.send(params);
    });
```

The Project is format as so

```
    chcFolder
      manifest.json
      tabchc.
         --dasForm.css
         --dasForm.html
         --dasForm.js
```

Comment: There's a whitespace in your url after `.us.west-` maybe that's why.

Comment: ah thanks for noticing that, but it is an error from formatting the code in SO. Thanks, i'll fix that

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Can you post what you are getting in your F12 developer tools network tab when you hit the endpoint? That would help demystify things.

Comment: @MoA , no errors. Nothing changes with the pop-up.

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali Dev Tools (while on www.google.com) The Number of responses does not change. the Alert in the code fires and displays, but not the XMLHttpRequest... Perhaps I'll make a repo..

Comment: Does it work in Postman? If yes, are you using AWS API Gateway? If so, you probably need to enable CORS.

Comment: @MoA yes, and there are no CORs issue. Just a simple url that should return a 200 response. This can be tested by running this in the command line.. curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "New item", "year": "2009"}' https://sdlurjb3zi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/contMang

Comment: @MasonSB I tried calling the service using Postman and it works. You're attempting to run the code on a client-side form, right? If that's the case, why do you think it's not CORS related? It could be a simple URL, but if your Gateway doesn't have CORS enabled, then it won't work. I am not 100% sure this is the issue here, but it might be.

Comment: @MoA This is my first FireFox "extension"/add-on/plug-in. It works as a pop-up. From what I have read on the documentation you need to set permissions which i have done. The Lambda function is open so it won't give a CORS issue... I am beginning to believe these extensions can't make outbound request...

Comment: @MasonSB I see. Curious, does it work with  a public GET request such as `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` ?