# Send JSON to Google App Script using POST method

Tags: ajax, json, post, google-apps-script

as the title says, I'd like to know if it's possible to send some sort of JSON to a google app script, using POST method. Once the JSON is sent, it will be handled by the google script.

Till now, I managed to send a post request using a standard html form with 3 inputs (I followed this guide: http://mashe.hawksey.info/2011/10/google-spreadsheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-form-postget-submit-method/). Now I'd like to move to an ajax call that send some json to the google script, but I don't know how..

using an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: "someSortOfData",
  success: function(data){alert("ok")},
  error: function(message){alert("fail")}
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

where "someSortOfData" is the actual data I'm sending (I tryed with json, simple text, html, etc). Any time I run the script, the call keeps entering the "error" function, and I don't know why.

As I told before, using a standard html form for submitting data works, so I presume the URL is fine. The problem is with the data I'm sending I think.. Maybe, server side, google script is not expecting anything different than text?

this is how the script (Server side) looks like

```
function doPost(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('active'));
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // get next row
  var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
  var col = 0;
  for (i in headers){
    val = e.parameter[headers[i]]; 
    cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
    col++;
  }

  //return sent data
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  for( p in e.parameters){
    panel.add(app.createLabel(p +" "+e.parameters[p]));
  }
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

I probably need to edit this code too, but first I was trying to send correctly json to the server..

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to say that the google script writes data coming from the post request into a google spreadsheet.

Comment: Where are you trying to make the AJAX call from? Is that a separate web app on top of Google Apps Script? Could you describe the high level separation you have here?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post I tried using ajax to submit the data without refresh but you run into cross domain/XHTTP security issues. The answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000020/ajax-post-to-google-spreadsheet highlights the example I use using a hidden iframe trick you might be able to modify

Answer (score -1):

As noted in comments, it does sound potentially like a client-side cross-domain-scripting issue.  Where the AJAX call is coming from is key - it seems GAS will generally give you a 200 even for errors in generating output, which should be "success".

You might change your `"fail"` message to be `alert("fail:" + JSON.stringify(message))` to get a little more debug info, but in the case of cross-domain-scripting block, info may be sparse (e.g., "No Transport").  Perhaps mhawksey's fix is the ticket, or try using JSONP mode of JQuery AJAX fxnality (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), especicially `dataType`, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery)).