# How do I create a web form that adds data to a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Tags: php, python, html, google-sheets

I currently have a Google Sheet that automatically calculates shipping cost, product cost, tax, etc -- after the client has entered the quantity, ProductType, PriceCategory, etc.

Now I would like to create a web form (to make it cleaner/nicer for the client) that will automatically update the Google Sheet when the client has filled out the form.

The client likes the automatic dashboards I've set up in sheets, and the fact that multiple people can access it easily, but wants an easier way to fill out the information when an order is made.

How do I make a web form that can update a Google Sheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX post to google spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000020/ajax-post-to-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: This is a very relevant question. To bad some force there idea's to this forum, to prevent others can't ask to the questions  they think are important for them

Answer (score 1):

I know it's bad practice to link here, as links can change over time, but google developers has an API that can make calls to google spreadsheets.

Take a look here:  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api?hl=en