# QR code to update spreadsheet

Tags: ajax, curl, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to update a spreadsheet using a QR code to mark attendance and I'm stuck halfway. I started with a [Google Sheets](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/) script update method where a form posts into a spreadsheet. So far that's working fine:

```
// fire off the request to the form
request = $.ajax({
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/[ID]/exec",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});
```

Since the script allows for `GET` requests as well, I'm trying to use `cURL` to send the data in the form of a URL which I can encode as a QR, which looks similar to this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30127428/1091386):

```
curl "https://script.../exec?FirstName=John&LastName=Fields"
```

However, I get a 302 response saying that the page has moved temporarily to `https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=...`

Trying to `curl` the data to this `script.googleusercontent.com` URL with the `--data` argument produces a webpage with a "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time."

Has anyone successfully produced a `curl`able URL?

By the way, I'm also looking at [AJAX post to google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000020/ajax-post-to-google-spreadsheet) which references [Hawksey](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/) too. If I can find something from there that works, I'll update.

Comment: Do you set redirects = true setup for curl? Something like this: `curl -L "https://script.../exec?FirstName=John&LastName=Fields"`. as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects).

Comment: This would be interesting and could answer the question as posed, thanks. However, I'm hoping to be able to fit this into a one-shot mechanism which I can scan, I suppose I'll have to wrap the `-L` part into a custom scanning app.